# How do I resolve my DNS through AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, ubuntu-14.04

I have Amazon EC2 instance running ubuntu. I have an elastic IP address also.

I have setup my domain and my DNS server.

I want to know how will I use AWS to connect to my DNS without using Amazon DNS server?

At first my website was running properly. But when I added the nameserver to list is my DNS of AWS it stopped working.

Comment: It's always worth googling before asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029877/i-bought-a-domain-and-i-want-to-apply-it-on-my-amazon-ec2-instance

Answer (score 1):

Edit the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` and put you server ip `nameserver 127.0.0.1` and run `sudo resolvconf -u` to update resolvconf

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to your domain register and set the DNS servers to point to yout ubuntu EC2 instance and  in the instance itself set the your ZONE file.
Another option is to use Amazon DNS (route53) and then set DNS server to point to amazon service on your domain register

Comment: how to set the zone file?

Comment: Please go to ubuntu documentation https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto